# Динамические (AJAX) запросы не работают в UI компоненте WebView

Tags: ajax, javascript, webview, android

**Доброго времени суток!**

В данный момент столкнулся с проблемой, когда динамические(AJAX) запросы не работают в UI компоненте WebView. Т.е, к примеру, запрос вида:

```
$.ajax({
        url:"http://www.site.ru",
        type:'POST',
        async:true,
        dataType:"text",
        success: function(d){alert(d)},
        error: function(d,er){alert('Error occured!')}
        });
```

Всегда приводит к ошибке( выполняется метод "error" и выводится соответствующее сообщение. ). Причем, проблема актуальна для версии Android 4.1+. Даже не знаю, почему такое вообще может происходить...Как вы думаете, в чем тут может быть проблема?

**Спасибо!**

Answer (score 2):

Оказалось, в API уровня 16( API Level 16 ), который начинается как раз с Android 4.1 была добавлена "особая" защита от подобного рода функционала. Вся проблема решается одной строчкой:

```
  mywebview.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```

А вообще, логичнее было бы просто устанавливать наиболее походящуюю версию API в AndroidManifest`е( если версия API на текущем устройстве выше targetSdk, то будет использоваться именно targetSdk ):

```
 <uses-sdk ... android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

Об этом также хорошо изложено в **[официальной документации](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)**.

Будьте осторожны, при работе с компонентом WebView в Android! Он таит в себе множество различных "загадок", которые однажды, возможно, придется разгадать и вам...